# Empty List using @ManyToOne and @OneToMany

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I try to use a bidrectional Mapping. First the Code:
**MapPoint**

```
@Entity
public class MapPoint implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private int x;
private int y;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
private GameMap map;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MapPoint() {
    super();
}   
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}   
public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}   
public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}   
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public GameMap getMap() {
    return map;
}
public void setMap(GameMap map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

**GameMap**

```
@Entity
public class GameMap implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="map")
private List<MapPoint> pois;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public GameMap()
{
    super();
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<MapPoint> getPois() {
    return pois;
}

public void setPois(List<MapPoint> pois) {
    this.pois = pois;
}
```

**Bean**

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("GameMap.findall");
return (GameMap) q.getResultList().get(0);
```

When I try to use it, my GameMap always has a emptry List of POIS. The Tables are created during Deployment and all Mappoint have MAP_ID set in Database by JPA itself, so it should be connected. My Question is, what am I doing wrong? I used this a lot in the past, but its a long time and any other similar Question here is not helping me.

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: Where is the code where you actually add to the List of POIS? With a bidirectional relationship you are required to handle both sides, JPA will not do this for you. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne

Comment: Can you please explain this a little more? I feel totally stupid at the Moment because I used to do this before :(

Comment: How is `GameMap.findall` defined ?

Comment: @NamedQueries(
@NamedQuery(name="GameMap.findall", query="SELECT map FROM GameMap map"))
It does work, but the List contains no Elements. The Rest works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManyToOne` relationships are Lazy loaded by default, if you want to eager load them you must specify that. Try:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="map", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<MapPoint> pois;
```

Or if you call `getPois()` inside persistence context, the list should be populated with data.

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Fetchtype.EAGER helped me, though I´m sure I never used it before and it still did what I wanted :)

Comment: worked for me too..but now <Optional> findbyid is not working..why :(